# Non-default storyboard not being copied after compile in XCode5

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization, storyboard, xcode5

I have a project that uses several storyboards. In starting to internationalize/localize it, I've begun differentiating the storyboards. However, I've found that non-default (i.e. not MainStoryboard.storyboard) files are compiled but not copied into the bundle. For instance, the following files are present:

```
./DerivedData/.../fr-CA.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc

./Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/.../fr-CA.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc

./DerivedData/.../fr-CA.lproj/Foo.storyboardc
```

BUT, this one is not:

```
./Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/.../fr-CA.lproj/Foo.storyboardc
```

Suggestions/ideas are welcome. I'm at the point where I'm considering writing a script to just copy over these resources manually, assuming that will even work.

Comment: When you look at your target settings and select the "Build Phases" tab, is this alternative storyboard included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" list? If not, tap on the `+` button and add it.

Comment: Yup, it's there. I also tried deleting and re-adding it, as well as cleaning out the DerivedData directory and doing a clean build.

Comment: @DavidCarney have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Nope. I put it on hold while I switched to working on other things with the hope that someone else would figure it out (or Apple would fix the apparent bug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, though "work around" is probably a better description:

1. Remove the storyboard (or XIB) from any Target Membership;
2. Do a clean build (and clean the build folder as well);
3. Close XCode;
4. Delete the app from the device/simulator;
5. Delete the contents of XCode's DerivedData directory (see Preferences);
6. Rebuild and launch the app, navigating to the area where the storyboard/XIB is expected (this should cause a crash);
7. Re-add the storyboard/XIB under Target Membership;
8. Rebuild and launch.

Step #6 is the most important. If the app doesn't crash it means that you have a cached copy of the file somewhere, which is no good. I have no idea exactly why this fixes things, though I wish I did.

After this, things work swimmingly (using Base Internationalization or not).